# Incoming WhatsApp images are saved twice in camera roll

Tags: iphone, photos, camera, whatsapp.app

I would like to have my incoming images on WhatsApp to be automatically saved on my iPhone's camera roll. In order to do so, I have switched on the 'Add to camera roll' option in WhatsApp settings.

Strangely enough though when I check the saved pictures in my camera roll, the pictures are all saved twice. In *random* order. I have no idea how this occurs. If anyone can help me out with this, that would be great.